# What is the proper HTTP status code to use for an expired JWT?

Tags: http, https, jwt, http-status-codes, http-status-code-400

Specifically for requests with an expired JWT (say, a password reset), what should the HTTP status code be?

Would `410 Gone`, be the most appropriate?

Comment: Why 410? *Has* the resource gone?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If the token is no longer valid, and the server no longer accepts that request, would it be argued that resource is "Gone"?

Comment: No, 410 means a resource used to be at that location but no longer is, not that you personally can no longer see it. Use e.g. https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html for finding appropriate responses.

Answer (score 0):

`401 Unauthorized` - most appropriate for your case.